# number of elements which have style attribute with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML.  I want to get the number of elements which have inline style.

Something like:

```
HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[has('@style')]").count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@style]").Count
```

You do not need to specify a value for the given attribute.